# How to Encrypt SQL file

Tags: sql, sql-server

sql) that contains all my stored procedures. Now I need the admin to run it in the database without him knowing the contents of the file.
How do I do this?

Ok I thought of running a .bat file that will run the script and deletes itself at the end. I already have the delete code as I have done it before. I only need to know now how to run sqlcmd in .bat file. Can you help me?

Comment: If I am a database admin, I would **never** add stored procedures if I am not allowed to see its contents.

Comment: I mean I sold the system to the client(admin) but not the source code. And I am not allowed to access the database since its already in production.

Comment: If your client accepts it; you should probably wrap it in an executable. Even so, if you execute the code, an admin will be able to see the stored procedure code. Since in SSMS you can always recreate a sproc, the code will never be secret.

Comment: How do I run .sqlcmd in .bat file?

Comment: That is a different question altogether. Please do your research, if you still have a question after that, feel free to post a new question.